# EditText.setText() not working in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `FrameLayout` in `CoordinatorLayout`. I am loading `Fragment` in the `FrameLayout`. But cannot set text of `EditText`s in the `Fragment`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = getActivity();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView       = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_info, container, false);

    etEmail             = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etFullName          = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etFullName);



    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_info, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    etEmail.setText("ggggg");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    etEmail.setText("ggggg");//LocalDBSP.init().getUser(context)
    etFullName.setText(LocalDBSP.init().getFullName(context));
}
```

I tried many. Many people says it's a bug. So, how do you set text in `EditText`?

Comment: You need to return the rootView to render the Fragment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your return statement to:

```
return rootView;
```

The `View` you're currently returning is not the one you're initially inflating and setting up.

Comment: Thanks this is the same problem and solution I faced.

Answer (score 1):

**Your Edit Text is there but you just set transparent background so you can't see it.**

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

EDIT since above didn't resolve the problem try to update the way you inflate your layout

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

aView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details2, parent, false);
EditText notatki = (EditText) aView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

//notatki = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
SharedPreferences settings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
notatki.setText(settings.getString("value", "raz dwa trzy"));
return notatki;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your onCreateView change the following line

> return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_info, container,
>   false);

**TO**

> return rootView;

then it would work all fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to changed your onCreateView like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView       = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_info, container, false);

    etEmail             = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etFullName          = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etFullName);

    return rootView;
}
```